# Java appending to text file working differently on another system?

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedwriter

When I run the below on a windows machine it works as expected, appending to the end of the text file on a new line, however when run in a jail on my FREENAS server inputs will simply append to the last line and never make a new line. Has anyone experienced this?

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename,true));
writer.newLine();
writer.append(desired);
writer.close();
```

Comment: You should print out what the new line separator looks like for the other platform. Might not be what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Despite the textfile looking like this after being given input on Windows:

```
cat
dog
mouse
```

and on FREENAS the textfile looking like this:

```
catdogmouse
```

They are both treated the same by Java and when read in with:

`String line = Scanner.nextLine();
 System.out.println(line);`

Both produce:

```
cat
dog
mouse
```